# Search for a question I viewed

Tags: support

A while ago I viewed a question in SF that was relevant to my interests, but I didn't mark it as favorite nor commented on it nor answered it. So I was trying to find a way to check the questions I've 'viewed', I looked into my profile but didn't find any tab that takes me there. Is there a way to find/search for questions I've 'viewed' only?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the current answer will help you. There is however a few possible reasons why a question you have previously seen could be difficult to find again: The title could have been changed. The question could have been migrated to another StackExchange site. The question could have been closed as a duplicate. The question could have been deleted.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I manually searched the question with the browser history and the question was indeed deleted.

Comment: In that case my comment is probably a suitable answer.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is not. Maybe look into your browser history.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the [answer](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/9448/214507) by [Sven](https://meta.serverfault.com/users/8897/sven) suggesting to check your browser history will help you.

There is however a few possible reasons why a question you have previously seen could be difficult to find again:

- The title could have been changed.
- The question could have been migrated to another StackExchange site.
- The question could have been closed as a duplicate.
- The question could have been deleted.

Users with 10k or more reputation and moderators have access to look at deleted posts. They also have access to look up recently closed questions and deleted posts.